# DllNotFoundException with DllImport in Mono on Mac: wrong architecture

Tags: c#, architecture, mono, interop, imagemagick

I'm trying to interop with the ImageMagick library in Mono on a Mac. I installed the ImageMagick library with MacPorts and have verified that the file **libMagickWand.dylib** exists in the directory **/opt/local/lib**. I've also created a soft link to that file in the directory **/usr/local/lib**.

Here's my DllImport statement:

```
[DllImport("libMagickWand", EntryPoint = "MagickWandGenesis")]
static extern void WandGenesis();
```

Here's my App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <dllmap dll="libMagickWand" target="/opt/local/lib/libMagickWand.dylib" />
</configuration>
```

And, at the call to `WandGenesis();`, I get a `DllNotFoundException`, with the message 'libMagickWand'.

I've read [this page](http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries) and I think I'm following all the rules. Is there anything else I can try?

**Update:**

I ran the .exe with MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug. Here is the pertinent information:

```
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'dlopen(/opt/local/lib/libMagickWand.5.dylib, 9):
no suitable image found.
Did find: /opt/local/lib/libMagickWand.5.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture'.
```

*wrong architecture*: I'm running Snow Leopard in 32-bit mode and always have. I installed ImageMagick with MacPorts, and I installed Mono with the Mac package from mono-project.com. What would have been compiled with a different architecture?

**Update:**

I think I found my problem:

```
MacBook-Pro:lib ken$ lipo -info libMagickWand.5.dylib
Non-fat file: libMagickWand.5.dylib is architecture: x86_64
```

**Update:**

...but I'm still having issues. I can't seem to figure out how to compile ImageMagick with i386 architecture. When I try to do so using flags, it complains about other libraries that were compiled as 64-bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:**

Mono on Mac OS X is 32 bit (at least usually, you can confirm that with `mono --version`) and you are trying to link with 64bit binary which is not possible. You have to provide 32-bit binary (or use 64-bit Mono).

---

Do you have the error even when only the library's file name is in the target and the library is placed appropriately (or the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH set)? In such case please provide the output of mono executed with MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug.

Comment: Thanks. I ran it with MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug and got some insight. I'll update my original question.